# Echo spits out weird characters

Tags: batch-file, echo

I'm trying to make a loading screen in batch just to have something to look at while the batch is making a timeout. When I type the code in cmd I just opend it works. But writing a batch file and launching it gives me this result:

Code:

```
timeout /t 1 /nobreak
cls
echo It's almost Done.
echo      Loading
echo ╔════════════════╗
echo ║▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░║
echo ╚════════════════╝
```

Output:

```
It's almost Done.
     Loading
ÔòöÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòù
ÔòæÔûôÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔûæÔòæ
ÔòÜÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòÉÔòØ
```

I don't understand where the problem is.

Why it is working when starting cmd via <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, but not when launching just the batch file.

Comment: I have finally saved the code you provided in my editor and got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph519.png) output. Not sure how you came to these unicode characters.

Comment: Can you please clarify if you want to `echo` what I mentioned above or the Unicode characters in your question? Unless you do that, the question is too broad. How did you came to these characters? Do you want to `echo` these?

Comment: What code page are you using? insert `chcp` followed by `pause` into your batch script and check the displayed value for both ways of running your script. Perhaps you need to put `chcp 437` or `chcp 850` (or something else?) into your script finally (followed by `> nul` to avoid display output)...

Comment: @double-beep OP wants the unicode characters, instead he is getting the output which he does not want.

Comment: I was using Alt Codes , aka holding alt with numeric input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get those characters to display, assuming your console font supports them, if you change the code page.

Add this to the top of your batch:

```
CHCP 65001 >nul
```

Your full batch would be:

```
chcp 65001 >nul
timeout /t 1 /nobreak
cls
echo It's almost Done.
echo      Loading
echo ╔════════════════╗
echo ║▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░║
echo ╚════════════════╝
```

[image: Results of batch]

Comment: Well i learned something new today , Thank you very much. You helped me a lot  !

Answer (score 0):

To ensure your Unicode characters save to your batch file and to ensure it runs the batch correctly with unicode characters, do the following:

Open `cmd.exe`

copy everything below and *"right click"* and paste the code, once pasted, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Please change however the `batch.cmd` name at the very end to your own script name before doing this:

```
chcp 65001
(echo @echo off
 echo chcp 65001
 echo timeout /t 1 /nobreak
 echo cls
 echo echo It's almost Done.
 echo echo      Loading
 echo echo ╔════════════════╗
 echo echo ║▓░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░║
 echo echo ╚════════════════╝
)>batch.cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could try this, which makes an assumption of the users console font etc.

```bat
Timeout 1 /NoBreak
ClS
Echo It's almost Done.
Echo      Loading
Echo ÉÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ»
Echo º²°°°°°°°°°°°°°°°º
Echo ÈÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍÍ¼
```